# Image not updated after changing it's File Path in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android

By facing image quality not decreased after compressing it multiples time I thought that plugin is not working. But after dumping file on File Storage during debugging, It was Actually Compressed and Image Quality was decreased by 25 %.

But Image is not Updating after setting it's State. I've read many articles and things. I've used all the things I've Found. I tried to clear Flutter's Image Cache and Painting Binding and Stuff. I also tried to empty temporary directory.

```
                    imageCache.clearLiveImages();
                    PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear();
                    var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
                    Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);
```

Here's My Code. First *_imagePath* is the image it receives and it's displayed properly. When we compress and update the File Path, Image's State is not changed (Image is not changed).

```
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 150,
            backgroundImage: FileImage(File(_imagePath)),
          ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  'Compress',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() async {
                    // Compressing File
                    File compressedFile =
                        await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
                      _imagePath,
                      quality: 25,
                    );
                    _imagePath = compressedFile.path;
                  });
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [Value Notifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) of flutter which notifies if value changes for image.